# Make Istio ignore connections between two containers in the same deployment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, istio

I have an OpenShift deployment with two containers: main java app and a custom sidecar that does jmx monitoring of the main app. So when I don't inject Istio sidecar (with annotation sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false') everything works as I expect and jmx sidecar can establish connection. But when I inject Istio sidecar I have connection problems.

There are annotations like:

- traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts
- traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts
- traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts

but they don't seem to work, at least in my case and I couldn't find much information about them.

Here is my deployment yaml with relevant information that works with 'false' and doesn't with 'true' Istio sidecar inject option

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mainjavaappsource
        ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
      - image: jmxsidecarsource
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
```

So the question is - how can I exclude connections between containers in the same deployment from being intercepted by Istio sidecar?

Comment: How are you trying to connect from one to the other?  (Within the same pod you should be able to use `localhost` as a host name.)  What errors are you getting?  Is it just connections within the same _pod_, or are you trying to make connections between pods in the same deployment?

Comment: It's a connection within the same pod. Yes, I'm able to use localhost: my jmx connection url string uses localhost - service:mx:rmi://localhost:9911/jndi/rmi://localhost:9911/jmxrmi

And my jmx library gives Connection reset error (java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment).

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the proxy from intercepting the traffic, basically means to exclude that service from the mesh. Simply don't inject the sidecar (so, keep that service outside the mesh), and create a `ServiceEntry`.

Comment: The thing is that I need my main app to be visible in mesh so I can't really just exclude Istio side car

Comment: visible in sense of telemetry?

Comment: In general sense I presume. Routing to my app works using Istio. But now when I add my custom sidecar for monitoring it doesn't work except when I disable Istio which is not a solution cause for reasons mentioned earlier